# Transform value from input to model using Pipe

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-pipe

For instance, let's consider the following scenario:

- Angular 5.2
- there is a two way binding using `(ngModel)` between `model` and `input` field  in the view.
- there is a `Pipe` used to show `model`'s *milliseconds* value as *seconds* in the input field.
- The user then want to type the value in *seconds*

Can I have a `Pipe` ( or something similar ) that transforms back the *seconds* into *milliseconds* ? A `Pipe` or something similar meaning NOT writing manually *" on value change "* handler methods in the component for each inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no.

If you want to convert your milliseconds to seconds from the model to the input, then yes, you can use a pipe. But if the user can change it, you will have to let go of the pipe, since pipes are used just to display values, and not to edit them.

Comment: Does that mean the only way stays the old "onChange" handler that manually set the model's value ? (or some custom home-made solution)

Comment: That highly depends on how you handle the user interaction in your view. If it's a form to send, then no, you don't need it. The best way that I can answer to you is if you give me the user scenario (context, interactions, goal)

Comment: oh, ok. The question is quite broad, and I wanted to know "in general", but specifically, current context is: A settings component where settings (inputs, sliders, checkboxes, ..) can be changed independently and on the fly. Currently, the values are directly "2 way plugged" into the settings model. And I remembered from long ago that .NET had something like the Pipe but that worked both ways, hence my question.

Comment: Then what are the milliseconds used for ? I don't recall any HTML input that uses time ... Maybe a datepicker ? And no, in Angular, the pipes are only for displaying formatted values

Comment: For that example specifically, code uses milliseconds for js timeouts and intervals. I can think of many ways (nothing specific to Angular as I don't know angular very well yet) of solving this problem, but wandering of what would be the easiest one, needing to write the less code as possible. Especially since I have other similar (but not identical) simple transformations to do.

Comment: if I were you, I would use getters and setters. Do you know them or do you need a quick edit to show it to you ?

Comment: I'm good, I do know them in other languages, but just didn't thought about that in typescript. That seems like a good Idea thank you !